# emcee MCMC Sampling... Small set of walkers not converging?

Tags: sampling, mcmc, log-likelihood, emcee

I'm running mcmc on a simulation where I know the true parameter values. Suppose I use 100 walkers and 10,000 steps in the chain. The bulk of the walkers converge to the correct parameter values, but ~3 walkers (out of the 100) just trail off into the distance, not converging. Not sure what could be at play here, other than a potential error on my end.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, I agree.

Comment: Where are the walkers initialized? If the log prob is multimodal and walkers are initialized too far from the global maximum they may get stuck in a local maximum.

Comment: Another alternative is for the log prob to return nan in some cases, provoking unexpected behaviours